# Visual Studio: Any extensions/addons can custom region painting?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, add-on

[CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) can [custom region painting](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/Visualization.xml) in the Code Editor. Any other extensions/addons have this feature?

Thanks

**Edit**: Changed title and contents for better description.

[image: CodeRush Region Painting]

Comment: I don't get the question. What do you mean "Visualise"? BTW, I'm glad I don't have to maintain your code, I can't STAND regions :)

Comment: Making collapsed regions visible, what will they think of next.  Shopping questions are off topic at SO: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: @OJ: By "visualize" I mean some visual effects like drawing vertical lines at `#region` and `#endregion`, as illustrated in the image above.

Comment: @OJ, @Hans Passant: I have changed title and contents for better description. Sorry for the confusion. English is not my native language.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I don't think this is a shopping question. Just like asking "_Which web browsers support HTML5_". I think this type of questions fall in the category of `software tools commonly used by programmers` that stated in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Everybody knows what HTML5 means.  The problem with your question is that somebody will research it, come up with a product and you might say "Nah, not quite what I had in mind".

Comment: @Hans Passant: I don't see the point of your statement. I already did a lot of search on this, but couldn't find an answer. So I post at here hoping other users who is using this kind of tool can give me a name or link of their tools. If you think this is a bad question, you can simply ignore it, or request close/flag.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean "horizontal", not "vertical" lines.

Comment: @OJ: Ah, yes. I always get confused with these 2 words. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @caveman, have a look to [VS10x](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1c54d1bd-d898-4705-903f-fa4a319b50f2/) extension. Is not exactcly what you ask for, but could helps.

Comment: Personally, I find this feature of CodeRush invaluable - without it regions are annoying.  With it, regions are absolutely essential.

I'm surprised more people aren't interested in this functionality.